# ExpressJS + serve-favicon + nginx

Tags: express, nginx

I'm having problems serving favicons with nginx as a reverse proxy in front of my express app.

Tried to search for answers but couldn't find any. My configuration file is as shown:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name vogueverve.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|w$
        root   /var/www/hashiontag/public;
    }
}
```

Please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: The question is a little confusing because you have mention `serve-favicon` and say you want `nginx` to serve the favicon.  Generally you would want to use either `serve-favicon` or `nginx`, not both.  Can you clarify how `serve-favicon` fits into this?

Comment: explain the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/308299/how-to-set-a-favicon-ico-for-a-specific-virtual-host-on-nginx#answer-308304

Apparently, for nginx, the default is to put the favicon at the root directory, because nginx directs the clients to get favicon from www.domainname.com/favicon.ico by default.

This means that, (I think) with nginx as the reverse proxy, the favicon request never reaches the express layer, and hence it can't serve it.